# Surefire is not picking up Junit 4 tests

Tags: maven-2, junit4, surefire

I cannot get Maven Surefire to execute my JUnit 4 tests even after I tried all the advices from another post.

My POM:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>maven-test</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.springsource.org.junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>  
  </dependencies>

  <build> 
    <plugins> 
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>  
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
      </plugin> 
    </plugins>
  </build> 
</project>
```

My Test:

```
public class TestSimple {

 public void testSurePass()
 {
  int x = 1;
  Assert.assertEquals(1, x);
 }

 @Test
 public void surePass()
 {
  int x = 1;
  Assert.assertEquals(1, x);  
 }
}
```

Surefire picked up testSurePass, but never saw surePass.  I tried mvn -X:

```
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[DEBUG] dummy:dummy:jar:1.0 (selected for null)
[DEBUG]   org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.5:runtime (selected for runtime)
[DEBUG]     org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.5:runtime (selected for runtime)
[DEBUG] Adding to surefire booter test classpath: C:\Users\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-booter\2.5\surefire-booter-2.5.jar
[DEBUG] Adding to surefire booter test classpath: C:\Users\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-api\2.5\surefire-api-2.5.jar
[DEBUG] dummy:dummy:jar:1.0 (selected for null)
[DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-providers:pom:2.5 for project: null:surefire-junit:jar:null from the repository.
[DEBUG] Adding managed dependencies for unknown:surefire-junit
[DEBUG]   org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.5
[DEBUG]   org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.5
[DEBUG]   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.9
[DEBUG]   org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit:jar:2.5:test (selected for test)
[DEBUG]     junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test (selected for test)
[DEBUG]     org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.5:test (selected for test)
[DEBUG] Adding to surefire test classpath: C:\Users\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-junit\2.5\surefire-junit-2.5.jar
[DEBUG] Adding to surefire test classpath: C:\Users\.m2\repository\junit\junit\3.8.1\junit-3.8.1.jar
[DEBUG] Adding to surefire test classpath: C:\Users\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-api\2.5\surefire-api-2.5.jar
[DEBUG] Test Classpath :
[DEBUG]   C:\Workspace\tests\maven-test\target\test-classes
[DEBUG]   C:\Workspace\tests\maven-test\target\classes
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\.m2\repository\org\junit\com.springsource.org.junit\4.4.0\com.springsource.org.junit-4.4.0.jar
[DEBUG] Setting system property [user.dir]=[C:\Workspace\tests\maven-test]
[DEBUG] Setting system property [localRepository]=[C:\Users\.m2\repository]
[DEBUG] Setting system property [basedir]=[C:\Workspace\tests\maven-test]
```

Surefire 2.5 adds junit-3.8.1 to its test classpath automatically.  Although junit-4.4.0 is also added (not to surefire test classpath, but Test Classpath), junit-3.8.1 seems to take precedence.  Maven's surefire-api project has a dependency on junit-3.8.1 according to http://maven.apache.org/surefire/surefire-providers/dependencies.html.

Am I missing some configuration here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surefire has a junit-version artifact detection mechanim that is being fooled by you using the junit artifact packaged by springsource. You need to set the [junitartifactname parameter](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#junitArtifactName)
to org.junit:com.springsource.org.junit

Answer (score 3):

I'm lost, I cannot reproduce your problem. But there is indeed a Jira issue (see [EBR-220](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/EBR-220)) explaining that you need to add the following to the surefire configuration when using the JUnit artifact packaged by SpringSource:

```
<junitArtifactName>org.junit:com.springsource.org.junit</junitArtifactName>
```

Comment: thanks Pascal! since krosenvold replied first with the same solution, i placed my check next to his.

Comment: @Candy No problem, that's perfectly appropriate actually. I just posted this answer for the Jira reference.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use JUnit 4.x with maven 1.x :

```
* add Junit 4.X in your dependencies
* Use the JUnit4TestAdapter in your test classes :
  /**

* @return instance of this as Junit test case
  */
  public static junit.framework.Test suite() { return new JUnit4TestAdapter(MyTestClass.class); }

* run maven with a jdk >= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this: [JUnit + Maven + Eclipse: Why @BeforeClass does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274573/junit-maven-eclipse-why-beforeclass-does-not-work/6168553#6168553)