# Mockito Testcase ignores annotations

Tags: java, maven-2, junit, mockito

I have a Spring web application and I want to make unittests for my controllers. I have decided not to use Spring to setup my tests but to use Mockito mock objects in conjunction with my controllers.

I build and run tests with Maven2 and the surefire plugin. This is from my pom.xml

```
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.org.junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0-rc1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I setup my compiler and surefire plugins like this:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
            </plugin>
```

My test class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EntityControllerTest {

private EntityController entityController;

private DataEntityType dataEntityType = new DataEntityTypeImpl("TestType");

@Mock
private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

@Mock
private EntityFacade entityFacade;

@Mock
private DataEntityTypeFacade dataEntityTypeFacade;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    entityController = new EntityController(dataEntityTypeFacade, entityFacade);
}

@Test
public void testGetEntityById_IllegalEntityTypeName() {
    String wrong = "WROOONG!!";
    when(dataEntityTypeFacade.getEntityTypeFromTypeName(wrong)).thenReturn(null);
    ModelAndView mav = entityController.getEntityById(wrong, httpServletRequest);
    assertEquals("Wrong view returned in case of error", ".error", mav.getViewName());
}
```

Annotations all around :-)

But when building from the commandline i get a NullPointerException in the line when(dataEntityTypeFacade.getEntityTypeFromTypeName(wrong)).thenReturn(null); as the dataEntityTypeFacade object is null. When I run my testcase in Eclipse all is well and my mock objects are instantiated and the method annotated with the @Before is called.

Why are my annotations seemingly ignored when running from the command line???

/Eva

Comment: By "building from the commandline", do you mean a maven build or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you called:

```
 MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(testClass);
```

in the base class or a test runner as mention here: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#9

Comment: I forgot to post this in the question: I have @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) above my test class definition. The way I understand it, I shouldn't have to call initMocs.

Comment: I read the doc and it sounds like you NEED the initMocks() line for it to work; it is in a bolded "Important!" section. It says you "may" use the Runner with it; I am not sure what the difference is with or without the Runner. But you for surely need this line. IMO - The @Mock annotations aren't as good as setting up the mocks manually.

Comment: @Gweebz: No, [the runner](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html) replaces that: "Initializes mocks annotated with Mock, so that explicit usage of MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(Object) is not necessary."

Comment: The testcase runs fine when I run it inside Eclipse but not when I run it as part of my Maven build. The @Before annotation is ignored as well. This leads me to believe that the issue probably has more to do with Maven (either the compiler plugin or the surefire plugin) than it has to do with Mockito. ???

Comment: I've been running JUnit3 all along. Setting the "junitArtifactName" configure parameter to "org.junit:com.springsource.org.junit" on the surefire plugin helped. The same problem is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182376/surefire-is-not-picking-up-junit-4-tests